# Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, Ethernet stopped working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, network-manager

As far as I remember, the last time I did not change anything in the laptop, but all things related to the network stopped working, I can't even update the kernel via USB tethering (Ethernet does not work). Attached the results of the commands `uname -r, ifconfig, nmcli, lspci | grep Intel, ls/lib/firmware | grep iwlwifi` here - https://pastebin.com/v6WpSDbp. I would be very grateful if someone would help.

Comment: I installed another version of the linux kernel, I think something happened during the kernel update, and it helped me.P.S. I installed kernel through my phone.